# Russian equivalent for "XOXO"?

Tags: перевод

There's [an issue](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4720/213987) with translation of some strings from Stack Exchange login screen into Russian:
[image: XOXO]
I've suggested the neutral 'С уважением, команда Stack Exchange' ('WBR, SE team'), but  something like 'Чмоки, команда Stack Exchange' seems more correct ([see urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=xoxo)).

Any ideas? ;)

Comment: "x means kisses, o means hugs" - т.е. это "целуем, обнимаем".

Comment: You do not need a comma before когда

Comment: Надо что‐то вроде "Приносим извинения за временные неудобства"и никаких "уважений " не потребуется. Хотите "неформальности", напишите просто "ваша команда..."

Comment: @A K what do you mean and what should I find there? Definitely there should be no comma here.

Comment: @Anixx I've read 'before команда', not 'before когда'. You're right: noneed comma there.

Comment: @anixx: of course you do need a comma before _когда_.

Comment: @AK: what did you end up using?

Comment: @Quassnoi safest one: 'С уважением'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Чмоки* would sound too sarcastic and out of tune with the rest of the message (which itself is a bit too much of officialese to my taste, not sure if intentionally or not). That's a deliberate mockery unlike genuine "hugs and kisses".

*С уважением* is the safest option here, but if you really want to be a little bit more personal here (and you don't until you rewrite the rest of the message in the same style), something a little bit outdated like *с рабочим приветом*, *крепко обнимаем*, *жмём руку* etc. would work too.

Answer (score 3):

`Но вы держитесь`

Frankly, offering hugs and especially kisses is a strange affair when presented to a person you just kinda failed and whom you don't have romantic or close friendship involvement with.

Answer (score 0):

"Ну, вы держитесь, там" would fit perfectly nowadays.

You can also add on this picture:
http://my-files.ru/97p3yl